# HP QuickTouch media keys worked with LiveCD but not after install

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, keyboard-layout, hp

The "touch sensitive keys", that control volume and media worked great out of the box when I was running Ubuntu on a LiveCD, but they are totally unresponsive after installation.

- HP Pavilion dv9740us with dual-boot Vista Ultimate and Ubuntu 10.10
- Intel Core 2 Duo T5450 / 1.67 GHz
- NVIDIA GeForce 8600M GS @ 512MB
- 3G DDR2 RAM,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can offer a workaround for this problem. Boot Windows (from stick, from disk, whatever) and make sure this Windows has installed the appropriate **HP Quicklaunch Button driver** (find it [here](http://www8.hp.com/in/en/support-drivers.html)). After starting Windows, use the touch buttons. If the buttons work, you can restart you laptop and boot ubuntu. It should work then, it did for me.

Although it is just a workaround, I hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely it was because there was a certain driver in use due to Windows/Vista being installed. During your LiveCD usage it's using the currently loaded drives from the main installation I.E. Windows and it uses those. When you install well, that all goes away. Most likely you'll need some proprietary driver or driver(s) if they even exist which I'm sure they do.

Comment: This is not accurate. The LiveCD does not load drivers from your Windows partitions, and they would be useless to the Linux kernel anyway. One potential cause is that the kernel installed differs from the kernel on the LiveCD ( http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1669646.html ) but I don't know why as yet.